# 40 sec delay with black screen during boot (ubuntu 17.1)

Tags: boot

I'm getting a 35 second delay during boot which I am unable to understand the reason about.

My PC running Ubuntu 17.10 Kylin, and Windows 10 dual boot.

After I select ubuntu in grub2, the screen goes black for around 40 second.
After that it boots without any problem.

I am investigating the reason behind 40 second time lag (black screen).

I am pasting here the `dmesg` log partially, other part I found ok less than 10 second time.

Please let me know what may be the reason which leads to a delay 9 second to 44 second in below attached log ??

Thanks in advance.

```
[    8.214117] systemd[1]: cgmanager.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit cgmanager.service is masked.

[    8.214130] systemd[1]: cgproxy.service: Cannot add dependency job, ignoring: Unit cgproxy.service is masked.

[    8.214513] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.

[    8.214580] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.

[    8.214660] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.

[    8.214668] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.

[    8.214691] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.

[    9.120540] lp: driver loaded but no devices found

[    9.299618] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver

[    9.352765] parport_pc 00:07: reported by Plug and Play ACPI

**[    9.352823] parport0: PC-style at 0x378, irq 5 [PCSPP,TRISTATE]**

**[    9.447629] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).**

**[   44.174264] EXT4-fs (sda6): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro**

**[   44.196588] systemd-journald[253]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1**

[   44.273870] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4

[   44.276587] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001828-0x000000000000182F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001800-0x000000000000187F (\PMIO) (20160930/utaddress-247)

[   44.276591] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver

[   44.276593] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C40-0x0000000000001C4F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20160930/utaddress-247)

[   44.276595] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver

[   44.276595] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20160930/utaddress-247)

[   44.276597] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C30-0x0000000000001C3F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20160930/utaddress-247)

[   44.276598] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver

[   44.276599] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C3F (\GPRL) (20160930/utaddress-247)

[   44.276600] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001C2F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000001C00-0x0000000000001FFF (\GPR) (20160930/utaddress-247)

[   44.276601] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver

[   44.276602] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich

[   44.298922] RAPL PMU: API unit is 2^-32 Joules, 4 fixed counters, 655360 ms ovfl timer

[   44.298923] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp0-core 2^-14 Joules

[   44.298924] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain package 2^-14 Joules

[   44.298924] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain dram 2^-14 Joules

[   44.298925] RAPL PMU: hw unit of domain pp1-gpu 2^-14 Joules

[   44.305521] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

[   44.305643] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])


[   44.305684] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)

[   44.307390] AVX2 version of gcm_enc/dec engaged.

[   44.307391] AES CTR mode by8 optimization enabled

[   44.319957] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D2: autoconfig for ALC892: line_outs=4 (0x14/0x15/0x16/0x17/0x0) type:line

[   44.319959] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC1D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)

[   44.319960] snd_hda_c
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention if you use Nvidia drivers. And if you have a fresh Ubuntu install or an upgrade.

On my upgraded system, I see the same problem on a Dell Precision 5510 laptop.  One time, the graphical login did eventually appear.  Two times, it has resulted in a black screen of death with cursor that shows and can move, but clicks don't have any effect.

I believe this traces back to the video driver.  I have both mainboard Intel and an Nvidia video card.  I had been using Nvidia.  There are reports of problems with Nvidia and Ubuntu 17.04, I expect that will get fixed in time.  To use the computer in the meanwhile, I stopped using Nvidia. There may be easier ways to get this (I think now I should have just removed xorg.conf files):

1. Alt-Ctl-F1, log in.
2. Run "startx", for me that did start X11, (but not a session managed login screen).
3. Run "nvidia-settings" and turn off Nvidia driver under Nvidia Prime, use the built in Intel instead. After that, there is no long black screen.

The fixup discussion on Nvidia drivers is already underway on many threads, I did try to update to the newest in the graphics driver ppa but I still have the black screen of nothing.

Back in Ubuntu 16.04, the Intel driver had some problems, such as "invisible cursor" after suspend & restart.  I'm hopeful that will not start happening again.

Comment: Thnkas for your feedback...I had ubuntu 16.14 +win10 dual boot. I just upgraded to ubuntu 17.04 kylin+win10.......After upgrade I purged the unused old ubuntu images....dpkg -l | grep linux-image.....then purged unused old image......then I repaied updated grub2......I had set uefi only in bios......Now my system directly boots into default OS win 10....boot menu grub appreas when I press F12 before boot.

Comment: Oh, well. I was hoping the black screen issue could be solved, at least. If you don't have Nvidia, my experience does not apply.

Comment: One point I want to tell about 17.10 is that I am feeling better after upgrade due to faster response on every app. Everything feel faster compared to 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too! Only way I got past the black screen was by choosing the "Advanced Options" and then "Recovery Mode" then "Resume Boot" (ignoring recovery options)

20 march 2019 update: specifically the reminder I am given when resuming is "some graphics drivers require a full graphical boot and so will fail when resuming from recovery". In this case FAILURE is SUCCESS.